# (Cura setting) How can I fix this? No top layer

Tags: ultimaker-cura, software

**problem solved by resetting cura.**

I have problems like this: How can I fix this? I can't find the right setting.

[image: No top layer]

Also, what are these yellow lines? Do you know how to remove them? They disappear when I disable to show the brim/raft/skirt.

[image: Yellow lines #1]

[image: Yellow lines #2]

Comment: Number of top layers set to zero?

Comment: I cant modify that setting.. when I tick the box in cura settings, it doesnt appear on the right side. The problem occurs on many different prints so it has to be the software.

Comment: I would suggest that you reinstall Cura. You must be able to configure the number of top and bottom layers.

Comment: Hi Donald, please could you post your answer (that a Cura reset was required (assuming that was the solution)) as an actual answer and marked *that* answer (and not Fernando's) as the accepted solution (using the tick button) and *not* in the question, as it breaks the Q&A format of Stack Exchange and will be confusing for other users of the site who come here looking for a solution.. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem appears when a face is inverted, so the slicer confuses and expect the other wall to close the object. So you need to reverse that face to show the face out and the back face inside the shape to be filled

[image]

*I will edit this answer with more examples*

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the yellow lines are showing the full path of the extruder head, including where it's retracted.  Somewhere in Cura's maze of menus, there's an option to turn on/off various displays related to the slicing.

As to why the top layer isn't there -- most likely it's too thin in your source  model.  You might try enabling "Print thin walls" options in the Preferences advanced list.  BTW, if you post the original STL or CAD file, we might be able to provide more accurate diagnosis.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly the thin wall option didnt solve the problem.. How can I upload a stl file?

Comment: @DonaldEnte  Best thing to do is upload it anywhere you have a repository (git, DropBox, GooglePages, etc) and put a link here